# How to make sense of SDE notation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have been trying to understand SDE notation and what it means but I cant seem to figure it out. Im sorry to post this question here, since this is probably elementary.

It is known to me that

$$ dX_t = f(X_t)dt + g(X_t)dW_t$$ basically means $\int_0 ^t d X_s = X_t - X_0 = \int_0 ^t  f(X_t)dt + \int_0 ^t g(X_t)dW_t$. So basically one just "leaves off" the integrals. I've now come across a problem where the situation is the following:

If $T$ is some finite stopping time, let $W^T _t := W_{T \wedge t}$ be a stopped Brownian Motion. For some time $T < t'$ consider the process $f(W^T _t)$, where $f$ is smooth. Show that $df(W^T _{t'}) = 0$. Intuitively this makes sense to me, since "the differential" (or whatever this quantity is called) should measure small changes and this process is constant for big enough $t'$. But I have no idea how to rigorously proof this, since I don't know how to manipulate $df(W^T _t)$ based on the "definition" from above. The only thing that comes to mind would be Itôs Lemma, but then I get a term like $\int_0 ^{t'} df(W^T _{s}) = W_T - W_0$, which, again, I dont know how to recover $df(W)$ from.

In more generality, I also came across something like

$$dX_t = f(X_t)dt + g(X_t)dW_t + dh(X_T).$$

How can I make sense if this? Again, I would assume that, because the third term does not depend on $t$ (but rather on $T$) that it just vanishes. But this is obviously not a rigorous argument and therefor Im really confused. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps this is like [differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)) with sequences of random variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is the intuitive explanation I was also thinking about. What you can do is choose $t'$ large enough and then do this "extension trick". This would yield $df(W^T _{t'}) = \frac{df(W^T )}{dt} dt = 0 $. My problem is that this doesnt seem very precise or justified (at least to me). Im not sure why/if one can do these things.

Comment: $\int_{t'}^{t''}df(W^{T}_{\tau})=f(W^{T}_{t''})-f(W^{T}_{t'})=f(W_{T})-f(W_{T})=0$

Comment: @Tobsn thanks for your answer! I think my main problem is: How does the quantity $\int _{t'} ^{t''} d f(W_\tau ^T)$ relate to $df(W^T _t)$ ? Doesn't this just show that $df(W^T _{t''}) - df(W^T _{t'}) = 0$  if $t'' \geq t'$?

Comment: They relate precisely in the same way as the SDE and its integral form you've written down in your post. $t'$ and $t''$ need to be bigger than $T$, their order is irrelevant.

Comment: @Tobsn Im sorry, but I still cant follow. Could you elaborate? If I know $\int _{t'} ^{t''} df(W^T _\tau) =0$, then, in differential form, $df(W^T _{t''}) - df(W^T _{t'})=0$ (or how else do I add the $t'$ as lower bound for $\int$?) . Of course, this tells me that $df(W^T _t)$ is constant after the stopping time is reached, but I dont see why this would tell me that  $df(W^T _{t''})=0$?!

Comment: No, $\int_{t'}^{t''}dM_{\tau}=0$ for any $t',t''>T$ is equivalent, or more precisely, is  the definining property for the statement $dM_{t}=0$ for all $t>T$

Comment: Ah okay, I did not know that. Do you happen to know a reference for this? I guess this is obvious if one interprets $dM_\tau$ as some sort of measure. But then, I am not sure how this relates to the differential notation, since I thought there one just forgets about the integral.

Comment: any reasonable book or lecture notes on stochastic analysis you like